# Set 'selected' value in Access multicolumn listbox

Tags: ms-access, listbox, set, selected, multiple-columns

I am using several bound ListBox controls on an Access form. The ListBox contents are related, so that, besides other things, when the user clicks on one ListBox, the selected row can change in others. All works fine, I have done this many times, as long as the ListBox has a single column. I use the super-simple VBA syntax 
    lstBoxWhosis = "SomeText"

and as long as the ListBox does contain that item, the selected row becomes the one containing that text, with no other search, find or reposition commands necessary.

My current headache is a multicolumn ListBox. The left-most column does not have unique entries, and when I use the above syntax, I get a reposition, but only to the FIRST row containing the text. I need to position according to the values in TWO columns. Is there some similar way to do this with multiple columns, or must I resort to searching the ListBox contents manually?

I've already tried concatenating the columns with space, comma and semicolon, also the syntax

> lstBoxWhosis = array("SomeText1","SomeText2")

No luck with any of those.

Remou:

I am doing it that way now, and it's actually fairly simple. Here's the code:

```
lstSpoje = lstKatastr
Do Until lstSpoje.Column(1) = lstOblast
  lstSpoje.Selected(lstSpoje.ListIndex + 1) = True
Loop
```

The first line positions directly to the start of the block in the first column, the second steps by one, checking the second column until it gets the correct row. The number of duplicates does not warrant a more efficient searching method. It works okay, except the display flutters during the repositions.

Otherwise, I posted everything I thought was pertinent. The ListBoxes are bound, as I stated in the very first sentence, which means they are based on a table or a query. If there is some other information that you think might help someone solve this, let me know what that might be.

Remou:

Yes, that would undoubtedly work. I actually already do something similar, one of the ListBoxes has almost 15,000 items, so to help the user locate stuff, I put in 26 CommandButtons, with letters, that move that ListBox to the start of that letter. I use the following code to positition the ListBox

```
x = ActiveControl.Caption
i = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Count(*) FROM TableOfKatastrs WHERE Left(Katastr,1)<'" & x & "'").Fields(0)
lstKatastr.Selected(i) = True
```

I may go to a similar scheme for this - it would get rid of the flickering problem and be faster to boot. But I was hoping for some little-known syntax with the simplicity of my first example, where one line of code does EVERYTHING:

```
lstBoxWhosis = "SomeText"
```

Remou:

I'd settle for two, since I'm using two columns. :) But seriously, the simple assignment syntax is so straightforward and elegant, and there's so often some odd phrasing that is little used, little known, that solves problems like this. I've tried all sorts of other things, like

```
lstSpoje.Column(1) = "SomeText2"
```

but all I get is syntax errors. Maybe it really is only applicable to the first (or only) column.

Comment: I am fairly sure you will have to iterate through the listbox to find the value you require. However, if the values are sorted, you should be able to skip to the first relevant value and work through the second column. Other options may be available if you have based the lists on a table. You may get other suggestions if you add a little more information.

Comment: It occurred to me that you could use a parallel recordset which could be ordered to match the list box and easily searched on two columns. This would get you an absolute value that could then be used as the index. The extra info I was thinking of was the rowsource of the listbox.

Comment: "where one line of code does EVERYTHING" not that I know of.

Comment: Another idea. Concatenate the two relevant columns in your rowsource SQL to create a third, hidden and unique column.

Comment: But how do I use that to locate a row, besides using a manual search? The assignment syntax seems to only operate with the first column; any other columns, including a joined one, I have to write code to look through the contents of the ListBox.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for something along these lines, and ran across this old post. I know this is down the road a ways, so this more in the spirit of filling in information for any future readers who may run across this while searching the archives.

I figured out another way of doing this - **DUPLICATE** the column (or concatenated columns into one column) by which I want to set the proper line of the list box, as the FIRST column, and make its width zero. It will not show, so the listbox will look normal to the user, but the standard syntax of

```
lstBoxWhosis = "value"
```

will then work normally.